# How to design a notification system in Shiny to evaluate the input value?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs, shinyalert

I would like to design a notification in Shiny to evaluate if the input values is equal to a specific number. The following code example is my attempt. This is a simple app checking if the input value is equal to `1000`. If not, a notification will show. I used `shinyalert` to create the notification and the `delay` function from the `shinyjs` package to avoid the situation that execution is too sensitive.

This app works but not perfectly. The problem is when the user types in a number. Sometimes it may execute the notification more than once. I believe it is related to how fast the user type in a number. For example, if I type in `5678` into the numericInput very fast, one notification will show, but if I type in `56` and then follow up with `78` very quickly (within a second). The notification will show twice. The app probably evaluates if `56` equals to `1000`, then moves on test if `5678` equals to `1000`.

If possible, I hope I can show the notification only once. I thought adding the `delay` function will help, but it did not, or perhaps I did not use the `delay` function in the right way. Please let me know if you have any feedback.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyalert)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  useShinyjs(),
  useShinyalert(),
  
  titlePanel("Check if the input text is 1000."),
  
  numericInput(inputId = "value_in", value = 0, label = "Input value")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$value_in, {
    req(input$value_in)
    delay(
      ms = 2000,
      if (input$value_in != 1000){
        shinyalert(text = "The input value is not 1000", 
                   type = "warning")
      }
    )
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use debounce or throttle.

Comment: @YBS Thanks. I tried these two before but do not work. Again, I may did something wrong, so I will look into these two later when I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Debounce` is the way to go. Below is some more about how it works, and then a minimal working example.

> Debouncing means that every invalidation from `r` will be held for the specified time window. If `r` invalidates again within that time window, then the timer starts over again. This means that as long as invalidations continually arrive from `r` within the time window, the debounced reactive will not invalidate at all. Only after the invalidations stop (or slow down sufficiently) will the downstream invalidation be sent.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyalert)
library(magrittr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    useShinyjs(),
    useShinyalert(),
    
    titlePanel("Check if the input text is 1000."),
    
    numericInput(inputId = "value_in", value = 0, label = "Input value")
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    #Create a debounced reactive, only runs when the input has changed and then been idle for 1000 milliseconds. 
    value_in_debounce <- reactive(input$value_in) %>% debounce(1000)
    
    observeEvent(value_in_debounce(), {

        print(paste('Triggered at', Sys.time(), 'Value is:', value_in_debounce()))

        if (value_in_debounce() != 1000){
            shinyalert(text = "The input value is not 1000", type = "warning")
        }

    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```